# S3 object deletion and s3 object existence

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

Can anyone help with checking s3 object existence and s3 object deletion using python3?
I found some methods to check object existence. But that was not a direct method.

[Here is the link which contains the indirect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842944/check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-bucket-in-s3-using-boto3)

I am still unable to find a method to delete the s3 object.

Comment: You use [`delete_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object) to delete objects and  [`head_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) to check whether an object exists... so it isn't clear what you are asking, here.

Comment: See the Amazon S3 section of AWS SDK for Python: [S3 — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)