# How to check for existence of multiple keys in s3 bucket in boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a long list of keys I want to check for existence in s3. They have different prefixes, and I want this to be fast, thus checking one by one won't do the trick.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376288/913098) checks one by one
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34562141/913098) assumes similar prefixes.

I need a call similar to the following

```
def keys_that_exist(keys: Sequence[str]) -> Sequence[bool]:
    return [True if i % 2 == 0 else False for i, key in enumerate(keys)] # just some example output.
```

How to do this without an API call to s3 for each and every key, using boto3 or another Python library?

Comment: Pretty much the only option is something like your second solution, just listing all of the objects in the bucket instead under a targeted prefix.

Comment: Agreed. There are no other options. Either `head_object()` each object, or list the relevant Prefix in the bucket and examine the response.