# Error while downloading file from S3 using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am encountering an error while downloading a file from `S3` programmatically. The code is give below.

The error is: `An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found`

```
import csv
import json
import boto3

def get_file(bucket_name, file_name, filename):
    try:
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        print("Inside get_file")
        with open(filename, 'w') as data:
            s3.download_file(bucket_name, file_name, filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        
toName_cfg = 'seo_input_config.cfg'
bucket = 'my-landing-dev'
internal_folder = 'input'
directory_remote = 'Seo'

get_file(bucket, f'{internal_folder}/{directory_remote}/{toName_cfg}', f"{toName_cfg}")
```

The S3 directory structure is:

```
my-landing-dev/input/Seo/seo_input_config.cfg
```

I tried finding a solution by searching the net, but couldn't get any conclusive answer. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Error is most likely because the file you're trying to access doesn't exist in S3.

Change the print statement to: `print(f"Inside get_file. bucket_name: {bucket_name}, file_name: {file_name}, filename: {filename}")` and confirm. To be absolutely certain that this is the problem [call `head_object()` before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376288/496289) trying to download it.

I.e. `s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)`

Also you are mixing download to an open fd or to a path.

download to a file by path:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

download into an already open fd:

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
with open('FILE_NAME', 'wb') as f:
    s3.download_fileobj('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', f)
```

See [official examples](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html).