# s3.meta.client.head_bucket returns error code 403

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm very new to the `boto3` package, and I'm trying to test out a simple `try/except` block that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871884/how-can-i-easily-determine-if-a-boto-3-s3-bucket-resource-exists) to identify whether the s3 bucket exists. So far I have:

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    "s3",
    aws_access_key_id=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_access_key_id'],
    aws_secret_access_key=self.settings['CREDENTIALS']['aws_secret_access_key'],
)

bucket = s3.Bucket(self.settings['S3']['bucket_test'])

for bucket_in_all in boto3.resource('s3').buckets.all():
    if bucket_in_all.name == self.settings['S3']['bucket_test']:
        print ("Bucket {} verified".format(self.settings['S3']['bucket_test'])) # This is triggered!

try:
    s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket=self.settings['S3']['bucket_test'])
    print("Bucket Exists!")
    return True
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    # If a client error is thrown, then check that it was a 404 error.
    # If it was a 404 error, then the bucket does not exist.
    error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
    if error_code == 403:
        print("Private Bucket. Forbidden Access!")
        return True
    elif error_code == 404:
        print("Bucket Does Not Exist!")
        return False
```

The bucket is found when I loop through `buckets.all()`, but somehow fails for `s3.meta.client.head_bucket`, throwing back error 403. Why? My end aim is to be able to look into an s3 bucket, and identify what files are there. I'm connecting from outside the cluster i.e. the script is currently not being run within the AWS 'cloud', but from my MBP connecting to the relevant cluster.

Comment: 403 is by permission, listbucket permission is required on the iam user you're using. You need to look at s3 docs, this isn't related to boto https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html

Answer (score 0):

may be that user has no auth of S3

you can make auth group and add user to group in aws console.